# Work with Mac on PC

Tags: macos

I am using a MacBook  running Snow Leopard and a PC running Windows 7.  They are both separate machines.  I want to work on both of these computers using just one monitor, keyboard and mouse. I would like a way to quickly switch between the two computers.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is the Mac a Mac Mini? If so you need a KVM type switch box with 2 USB ports and a HDMI port. If you find one let me know because I want the same, but they are all pretty over the top and expensive!

Answer (score 0):

Despite my comment above, [here is a cheap one on sale in the UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Switch2-KVM-For-Mini/dp/B000HA45X6).

I'm sure you can find one more local.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options when it comes to using multiple operating systems.

I currently have a 3 comp setup at work. I have a Windows PC, a Linux PC and a Mac Mini. I use one keyboard and mouse for them all, but no KVM. I use synergy to work between them. This is not a great option over wireless or on a laggy network.

You also of course can use a KVM if you would rather the switch be hardware based instead of software based.

You can use VNC or some other remote desktop software so the Windows 7 PC can remote into the Mac and control it.